Cannot get dataframe.['col1].median() to ignore nulls
I have pandas dataframe df1 with a 'rating' column. I Need the median of that column. The column contains the string 'Not Given' for missing values. I have replaced the 'Not given' values Numpy's np.nan and None using the Line:
df1.loc[df1['rating'] == 'Not given', 'rating'] = np.nan

OR
df1.loc[df1['rating'] == 'Not given', 'rating'] = None

and verified the results. Then tried to get the median of df1['rating'] using this line:
mrat_y =df1['rating'].median( skipna = True)

The error message I get using either null substitute is:
  File "C:\Users\fnaso\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 787, in nanmedian
    raise TypeError(f"Cannot convert {values} to numeric")
TypeError: Cannot convert [nan nan '5' ... nan '5' nan] to numeric

I am using Pycharm community edition with the latest Python version.
So either the replacements are not valid Nulls or median( skipna = True) is working as I expect or (most likely) I am missing something with my newbie head up my ass.
This works with the W3Schools_Tryit_Editor.
I was expecting to find the median of a panda dataframe column that has float8 and Null values.

Please read [mre] - how are you setting up this DataFrame? What is a small example we can use to reproduce the porblem?

@Anerdw I agree. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples

The type of the rating column is string ('5', '3', 'Not given' ...), you need to convert it to numeric.
You can use pd.to_numeric:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'rating': ['5', 'Not given', '3', '4', 'Not given', '5']})

df["rating"] = pd.to_numeric(df.rating, errors='coerce')
df


Note : Using coerce for errors mean that invalid parsing will be set as NaN (liek "Not given").

Output:
index,rating
0,5.0
1,NaN
2,3.0
3,4.0
4,NaN
5,5.0

Then you can calculate the median:
df['rating'].median( skipna = True) 


I relaced all of the "Not given" cells with np.nan and verified that they were all replace. The problem remains that xyz.median( skipna = True) DOES NOT SKIP np.nan or None values. Thank you.

FYI, you can't have a df column with mixed types .
that mean if 'Not given' is a str , all the other values in same columns are considered str(obvious from the the '5' in the error message )

You did not convert this str('5') to a numeric, that why I suggested pd.to_numeric and it will handle filling the 'Not given' with Nan alsi
